# Perfect Squares - Can someone explain following math?

Tags: c, math, square-root, perfect-square

**Problem Statement:**

```
Given a positive integer n, find the least number of perfect square numbers (for example, 1, 4, 9, 16, ...) which sum to n.

Example 1:

Input: n = 12
Output: 3 
Explanation: 12 = 4 + 4 + 4.

Example 2:

Input: n = 13
Output: 2
Explanation: 13 = 4 + 9.
```

Using the following knowledge about squares (given below) we can implement the following solution.

> A natural number is...
>
> 1. ... a square if and only if each prime factor occurs to an even power in the number's prime factorization.
> 2. ... a sum of two squares if and only if each prime factor that's 3 modulo 4 occurs to an even power in the number's prime factorization.
> 3. ... a sum of three squares if and only if it's not of the form 4a(8b+7) with integers a and b.
> 4. ... a sum of four squares. Period. No condition. You never need more than four.

```
int numSquares(int n) {
    while (n % 4 == 0)
        n /= 4;
    if (n % 8 == 7)
        return 4;
    for (int a=0; a*a<=n; ++a) {
        int b = sqrt(n - a*a);
        if (a*a + b*b == n)
            return 1 + !!a;
    }
    return 3;
}
```

**Question:**

Can someone help me understand what exactly are we trying to achieve in following for loop?
I'm a little lost here.

```
for (int a=0; a*a<=n; ++a) {
    int b = sqrt(n - a*a);
    if (a*a + b*b == n)
        return 1 + !!a;
}
```

Comment: `return 1 + !!a;` is the same as `if(a == 0) return 1; else return 2;`. Then you have the 4 `return` values for the 4 possible cases.

Comment: Thanks, but what are we achieving when we do `b = sqrt(n - a*a)` ? I specially don't understand why `n - a*a` ?

Comment: That checks to see if `n` is a sum of two squares, which happens iff `n - a * a` is itself a perfect square for some `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is trying to find two squares that sum to `n`.

Rather than trying every combination of numbers to see if we can square them and they add up to `n`, we just loop through the possibilities for one of the numbers -- this is `a`. We square that with `a*a`, and subtract that from `n`. We then get the integer part of the square root of this difference, and this is `b`. If a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup> adds up to `n`, this is the pair of squares that we're looking for.

We need to calculate the sum of the squares in case `n - a*a` wasn't a perfect square. In that case its square root will have a fraction in it, which will be lost when we convert it to an integer. In other words, testing `a*a+b*b == n` allows us to determine whether the square root was an integer.

Comment: thanks ! I did draw this on white board, but instead of using a tree/graph approach I used a recursive call approach to instantiate and write down all the possible calls for `n=13` and I ended up making life difficult for myself. I later on drew a tree out of it for `n=7`, it made more sense to me, along with your explanation of course ! appreciate the help !